# Parsing Challenge - Fixing Broken Syntax

Tags: regex, parsing, sed

I have thousands of lines of code making use of a particular non-standard syntax. I need to be able to compile the code with a different compiler, that does not support this syntax. I have tried to automatize the changes that need to be made, but being not very good with regex etc. I have failed.

Here is what I want to achieve: currently in my code an object's methods and variables are called/accessed with the following possible syntaxes:

```
call obj.method()
obj.method( )
obj.method( arg1, arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1 )
obj1.var = obj2.var2
```

Instead I want this to be:

```
call obj%method()
obj%method( )
obj%method( arg1, arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1 )
obj1%var = obj2%var2
```

And I want to make these changes without effecting the following possible occurrences of "."s:

Decimal numbers:

```
a = 1.0
b = 1.d0
```

Logical opertors (note possible spaces and method calls):

```
if (a.or.b) then
    if ( a .and. .not.(obj.l1(1.d0)) ) then
```

Anything that is commented (the exclamation point "!" is used for this purpose)

```
!>I am a commented line.
   ! > I am.a commented line with..leading blanks and extra periods.1.
b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) !! I contain a commented version of this line: b=a1.var( 0.d0 )
```

Anything that is in quotes (i.e. string literals)

```
c = "I am a string"
c= 'I am an obnoxious string: b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) ... '
```

Does anyone know how to approach this. I guess regex is the natural approach, but I am open to anything. (In case anyone cares: the code is written in fortran. ifort is happy with the "." syntax; gfortran isn't)

Comment: Put all of your input examples in 1 file so we just have 1 input file to test with and provide the expected output for that file. Add a more complicated example that has to be handled, e.g. `c="I am a string!"; b=a1.var()` would be tricky because in that case the `!` is not the start of a comment.

Comment: Isolating method calls is pretty easy. The difficult part will be matching things like `obj1.var = obj2.var2` without matching `b = 1.d0`. I'm not sure you'll be able to write a pattern tight enough to change what you want without changing *more* than what you want.

Comment: Maybe you could try doing it in two steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into solving the problem with [flex](https://www.gnu.org/software/flex/)? It uses regular expressions, but is more advanced, as it tries different patterns and returns the longest matching option. The rules could look like this:

```
%%                                           /* rule part of the program */
!.*\n                     printf(yytext);    /* ignore comments */
\".*\"|'.*'               printf(yytext);    /* ignore strings */
[^A-Za-z_][0-9]+\.        printf(yytext);    /* ignore numbers */
".and."|".or."|".not."    printf(yytext);    /* ignore logical operators */
\.                        printf("%%");      /* now, replace the . by % */
[^\.]                     printf(yytext);    /* ignore everything else */

%%                                           /* invoke the program */
int main() {
    yylex();
}
```

You may have to modify the third line. Currently it ignores any `.` that occurs after any number of digits, if there is none of the characters from `A` to `Z`, from `a` to `z` or the character `_` before the digits. If there are more legal characters in identifiers, you can add them.

If everything is correct, you should be able to turn that into a program. Copy it into a file called `lex.l` and execute:

```
$ flex -o lex.yy.c lex.l
$ gcc -o lex.out lex.yy.c -lfl
```

Then you have the C program `lex.out`. You can just use that in the command line:

```
cat unreplaced.txt | ./lex.out > replaced.txt
```

This uses the same principle as Ed Mortons suggestion, but it uses flex so we can skip the organization. It still fails in some cases like having `\"` inside strings.

#### Sample input

```
call obj.method()
obj.method( )
obj.method( arg1, arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1 )
obj1.var = obj2.var2
a = 1.0
b = 1.d0
if (a.or.b) then
    if ( a .and. .not.(obj.l1(1.d0)) ) then
!>I am a commented line.
   ! > I am.a commented line with..leading blanks and extra periods.1.
b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) !! I contain a commented version of this line: b=a1.var( 0.d0 )
c = "I am a string"
c= 'I am an obnoxious string: b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) ... '
c="I am an exclaimed string!"; b=a1.var()
```

#### Output

```
call obj%method()
obj%method( )
obj%method( arg1, arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1 )
obj1%var = obj2%var2
a = 1.0
b = 1.d0
if (a.or.b) then
    if ( a .and. .not.(obj%l1(1.d0)) ) then
!>I am a commented line.
   ! > I am.a commented line with..leading blanks and extra periods.1.
b=a1%var( 0.d0 ) !! I contain a commented version of this line: b=a1.var( 0.d0 )
c = "I am a string"
c= 'I am an obnoxious string: b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) ... '
c="I am an exclaimed string!"; b=a1%var()
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the idea. I just added that and it does indeed give the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this 100% robustly without a language parser (e.g. the following will fail in some cases if you have `\"` inside double quoted strings - easily handled but just one of many possible failures not covered by your use cases) but this will handle what you've shown us so far and a bit more. It uses GNU awk for gensub() and the 3rd arg to match().

**Sample Input:**

```
$ cat file
call obj.method()
obj.method( )
obj.method( arg1, arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1 )
obj1.var = obj2.var2
a = 1.0
b = 1.d0
if (a.or.b) then
    if ( a .and. .not.(obj.l1(1.d0)) ) then
!>I am a commented line.
   ! > I am.a commented line with..leading blanks and extra periods.1.
b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) !! I contain a commented version of this line: b=a1.var( 0.d0 )
c = "I am a string"
c= 'I am an obnoxious string: b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) ... '
c="I am an exclaimed string!"; b=a1.var()
```

**Expected Output:**

```
$ cat out
call obj%method()
obj%method( )
obj%method( arg1, arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1 )
obj1%var = obj2%var2
a = 1.0
b = 1.d0
if (a.or.b) then
    if ( a .and. .not.(obj%l1(1.d0)) ) then
!>I am a commented line.
   ! > I am.a commented line with..leading blanks and extra periods.1.
b=a1%var( 0.d0 ) !! I contain a commented version of this line: b=a1.var( 0.d0 )
c = "I am a string"
c= 'I am an obnoxious string: b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) ... '
c="I am an exclaimed string!"; b=a1%var()
```

**The Script:**

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    # give us the ability to use @<any other char> strings as a
    # replacement/placeholder strings that cannot exist in the input.
    gsub(/@/,"@=")

    # ignore all !s inside double-quoted strings
    while ( match($0,/("[^"]*)!([^"]*")/,a) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[1] "@-" a[2] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    # ignore all !s inside single-quoted strings
    while ( match($0,/('[^']*)!([^']*')/,a) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[1] "@-" a[2] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    # Now we can separate comments from what comes before them
    comment = gensub(/[^!]*/,"",1)
    $0      = gensub(/!.*/,"",1)

    # ignore all .s inside double-quoted strings
    while ( match($0,/("[^"]*)\.([^"]*")/,a) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[1] "@#" a[2] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    # ignore all .s inside single-quoted strings
    while ( match($0,/('[^']*)\.([^']*')/,a) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[1] "@#" a[2] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    # convert all logical operators like a.or.b to a@#or@#b so the .s wont get replaced later
    while ( match($0,/\.([[:alpha:]]+)\./,a) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "@#" a[1] "@#" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    # convert all obj.var and similar to obj%var, etc.
    while ( match($0,/\<([[:alpha:]]+[[:alnum:]_]*)[.]([[:alpha:]]+[[:alnum:]_]*)\>/,a) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[1] "%" a[2] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    # Convert all @#s in the precomment text back to .s
    gsub(/@#/,".")

    # Add the comment back
    $0 = $0 comment

    # Convert all @-s back to !s
    gsub(/@-/,"!")

    # Convert all @=s back to @s
    gsub(/@=/,"@")

    print
}
```

**Running The Script And Its Output:**

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
call obj%method()
obj%method( )
obj%method( arg1, arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1 )
obj1%var = obj2%var2
a = 1.0
b = 1.d0
if (a.or.b) then
    if ( a .and. .not.(obj%l1(1.d0)) ) then
!>I am a commented line.
   ! > I am.a commented line with..leading blanks and extra periods.1.
b=a1%var( 0.d0 ) !! I contain a commented version of this line: b=a1.var( 0.d0 )
c = "I am a string"
c= 'I am an obnoxious string: b=a1.var( 0.d0 ) ... '
c="I am an exclaimed string!"; b=a1%var()
```